# Wordpress behind nginx reverse proxy, not able to access admin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Laravel application setup on https://staging.qivarna.com - This runs on nginx

I have setup wordpress blog on http://test.qivarna.com - This runs on nginx

Both work very well.

I am using nginx reverse proxy with the following setup in nginx file:

```
location /blog/ {
  proxy_pass http://test.qivarna.com/;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

And in wp-config.php:

```
if ( (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) ||
     (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ) {

    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];

    define('WP_HOME', 'https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/');

    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

I can access https://staging.qivarna.com/blog and it works fine. But when I access https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/wp-login.php or https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/wp-admin to access admin, it says "No input file specified."

So, for now I am accessing http://test.qivarna.com/wp-admin/ to get the work done, but how to fix the issue of "No input file specified." which happens only when I try to access admin.

Edit:

Nginx config for test.qivarna.com:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: have you specified document root setting in nginx file?

Comment: Please add the nginx config for test.qivarna.com.

Comment: Try `location ^~ /blog/ { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Though ^~ seems to have work, after I do https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/wp-admin/ It redirects to https://staging.qivarna.com/wp-admin/, and it opens my main website. And I  face input file not specified issue after entering admin.

Comment: Does `https://staging.qivarna.com/blog/wp-admin/` work? The redirect may be caused by your webserver on `test.qivarna.com` rather than WordPress. You can fix specific redirect issues using one or more [`proxy_redirect` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Comment: @rjvim have you ever figured out the problem? I have same issue